# passing data from child to parent component - react - via callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

passing data from child to parent component via callback function
but somehow it's not working.
what am I doing wrong here?
passing data from child to parent component - react - via callback function

https://codepen.io/silentarrowz/pen/GEMQEP?editors=0010

and here's the code

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        input:'this is the input for now'
      }
   //this.handleInput=this.handleInput.bind(this);   
    }

    handleInput(x){
      this.setState({
        input:x
      });
      alert(this.state.input);
    }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Passing props from Child to Parent Component</h1>
        <Child getInput={this.handleInput} />
        here's the input: {this.state.input}
        </div>
    );
  }
 }

class Child extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      text:''
        }
    }
  passingProps(e){
    var newInput=e.target.value;
    //alert(newInput);
   this.setState({
     text:newInput
    });
  this.props.getInput(this.state.text);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="please input a name..." onChange={this.passingProps} />

        </div>

    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

1) You have to bind `passingProps`

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      text:''
    }
    this.passingProps = this.passingProps.bind(this);
}
```

2) `this.setState` is asynchronous, so it's not guaranteed that `this.state.text` will be set to the value you want by the time you pass it to `this.props.getInput`. You can either do

```
this.props.getInput(newInput)
```

or

```
this.setState({ text: newInput }, () => {
  this.props.getInput(this.state.text);
})
```

to resolve that issue.

Comment: thanks. that really helped a lot.
I didnt know setState is asynchronous

Comment: @DonovanM hi I'm having a similar issue,but this isn't solving my problem

Comment: @JohnAnisere what issue are you having? It'll probably be easier to add a new question

Comment: @DonovanM What if the child class is a function instead of a class? Can you assist me 
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-architecture-qkldm?file=/src/FieldData.js

Answer (score 2):

```
class App extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    input:'this is the input for now'
  }
  this.handleInput=this.handleInput.bind(this);   
}

handleInput(event){
  let value = event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    input:value
  });
}

render(){
   return(
     <div>
       <h1>{this.state.input}</h1>
       <Child getInput={this.handleInput} />
     </div>
   );
  }
}

 class Child extends React.Component{
   constructor(){
      super(props);
}

render(){
   return(
     <div>
     <input type="text" placeholder="please input a name..." onChange={this.props.getInput} />
    </div>

     )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Here is the answer for your question. I hope your proplem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not automatically bound in your passingProps function.  Try arrow function syntax to bind it.

```
passingProps = e => {
  var newInput=e.target.value;
  //alert(newInput);
  this.setState({
    text:newInput
  });
  this.props.getInput(this.state.text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Child` Component, you have written following code:

```
passingProps(e){
  var newInput=e.target.value;
  //alert(newInput);
  this.setState({
     text:newInput
  });
  this.props.getInput(this.state.text);
}
```

The issue is due to the **asynchronous** behaviour of setState function. It means you can not call setState on one line and expect its updates on next line.
Use the callback function of setState to call the function of parent component just like this:

```
passingProps(e){
  var newInput=e.target.value;
  //alert(newInput);
  this.setState({ text: newInput }, () => {
     this.props.getInput(this.state.text);
  })
}
```

Same thing is happening in **handleInput** function of App component.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that you need to correct it:

1. if you want to access new state, you don't use `this.state.input` after 
   `this.setState({input: 'xxx'})`. [Here is reason why not it.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)
2. `this.passingProps = this.passingProps.bind(this)` is defined what `this` is current scope. when you use `this` in component's function, `this` need to be bind.

Changed [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzEWwJ?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method in parent that accepts some data and then sets the received data as parent state.
Then pass this method to child as props. Now let the method accept child state as input and then let the method set the received child state as parent state.

[image: Passing Child State to Parent]